# Google Analytics event tracking not firing in Ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-analytics

I have the following snippet of code:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $('#thanks').modal();

    $('#thanks').on('shown', function () {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Form Submit', 'Clicks_Submit', 'Request_Appointment']);
        var axel = Math.random() + "";
        var a = axel * 10000000000000;

        var $iframe = $('<iframe/>');
        $iframe.attr('src', 'https://doubleclickurlexampleignore' + a + '?');
        $iframe.width(1).height(1);
        $iframe.attr('frameborder', '0');
        $iframe.css('display','none');

        $('body').append($iframe);
    });
});
```

The #thanks modal shows fine, and according to the GA debugger chrome extension, my GA event is tracked correctly:

```
_gaq.push processing "_trackEvent" for args: "[Form Submit,Clicks_Submit,Request_Appointment]":  ga_debug.js:25
```

Other events on the page are being tracked fine (that aren't called via Ajax). Any ideas? I included the doubleclick code just in case that was somehow interfering.

Comment: In the GA debugger, is the correct account ID showing up in the tracking beacon gif for the _trackEvent?

Comment: It is, the same as the other events which are showing up fine

Comment: Any filters on the profile that might be removing the 'Form Submit' events? Also, are you testing against a live server, or on a localhost/intranet machine?